# Removing variables loaded by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading HTML/JS content via AJAX. When I load this request again, the variables can't be declared, because they already exist.

The project is supposed to load other sites via AJAX if a menu item is clicked. I have tried wrapping the contents in an `if(!loaded)` statement but when I load another site, the variables from the previous site remain.

Simplified example:

**load.php**

```js
let hello = 'Hello World'; //EDIT: const -> let
function sayHello(){

    console.log(hello);

}
```

**index.php**

```js
$.ajax('load.php', {
    success: function(data){
        $('body').html(data);
        sayHello();
    }
});
```

I want to delete `hello` and `sayHello` before the next AJAX request is fired or at least override them.

What is the best approach to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `let` instead of `const`. You can reassign to `let` declared variable but not `const`

Comment: Updated my question. I actually used `let` in my project. The outcome is the same tho: `Identifier 'hello' has already been declared`

Comment: ok but next time you don't use `let` ... just assign new value to variable name

Comment: `let` and `const` can't be re-declared. `var` can but I'd seriously look at a better way to do this. For example, have your AJAX response return data instead of functionality, eg `{"hello":"Hello World"}`